# Is it possible to do Bitwise OR assignment between unsigned int and unsigned short

Tags: c

trying to understand what could be the result of code block below. 
Does this mean we setting bits in first element of array ?

`U16_SET_BIT(candidates[1], 0);`

Does this mean we are taking constant 1 of type unsigned int and doing bitshift by n bits, in this case it would be 0.

```
#define U16_CREATE_MASK(n) (1U << (n))
```

It is next OR part I'm more confused about. Operation above will give us 32bits and then we trying to do OR with 16bits ?

```
#define U16_SET_BIT(u, n) (u |= U16_CREATE_MASK(n))
#define U16_CREATE_MASK(n) (1U << (n))
#define U16 unsigned short

int main(void) {
....
   U16 candidates[13];
   U16_SET_BIT(candidates[1], 0);
....
}
```

Comment: When you store a 32-bit unsigned value in a 16-bit unsigned variable, the upper bits are discarded.   Also, `candidates[1]` is the second element of the array. Arrays are indexed from 0 in C.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: Answer depends on if the size (range) of  `int` is greater than `short`.

Comment: Use `stdint.h` types instead of this legacy homebrew crap. And enable warnings. Note: `int` and `short` can have the same width.  I do not see 32 bit values here.

Comment: @M.M yes, that make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
U16_SET_BIT(candidates[1], 0);
```

> Does this mean we setting bits in first element of array ?

Yes, it'd set the second (counting from 0) element's LSB to 1.

> Does this mean we are taking constant 1 of type unsigned int and doing bitshift by n bits, in this case it would be 0.

Yes. This is done to get the correct mask value to do the OR operation later.

> Operation above will give us 32bits and then we trying to do OR with 16bits ?

Before shifting both the operands are promoted. Hence you'd have both operands of the size of an `int`. Post the shift, if you assigned it to a narrower type, the conversion would be implementation-defined. Generally you'd value modulo 2<sup>n</sup> as the result, where *n* is the number of bits in the destination type. This essentially means the higher-order bits are discarded.